# named function expression with let or const in es6?

Tags: function, ecmascript-6

I am changing my es5 code to es6 in my Angular 1.6 file(s) so started using `let` and `const` instead of `var` but quite confused about named function expression whether it should be `const` or `let` ?

#### es5

```
var foo = function () { ... }
```

#### es6

```
let foo = () => { ... }
```

or

```
const foo = () => { ... }
```

does mixing `let` and `const` within same js file for named function does impact the performance or we should stick with `var`?

In my understanding, functions are the things that always unchangeable in one JS file so we can use `const`.

Please give some useful explanation.

Comment: Performance questions on JS are almost always answered as "measure it" because it entirely depends between JS versions and engines.

Comment: and how one measure it? any perf tool/technique as I am not so hardcore JS developer

Comment: @loganfsmyth Since this is Angular, he is most likely writing in TS, and most likely transpiling to ES5, and assuming that's the case there obviously are no performance implications.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention but I am using *Angular 1.6*, so not using TS.

Comment: @loganfsmyth ...and depends on time, because it probably will change with the next version of engines.

Comment: @ftor I think `JS versions and engines` covers that? Those obviously change over time.

Comment: @loganfsmyth You're right. I just wanted to point out how largely unnecessary questions regarding performance are on SO.

Comment: [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) also raise same concern but no clear answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for `const` vs. `let` are the same whether you are assigning a function or any other value. If you don't intend or want to change the value (nearly always the case for functions), use `const`. However, notice that there are differences in hoisting behavior, although it is unlikely that would affect you.

Any performance difference will be negligible.